# Div BG img filling a width and height of a cell div parent

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid, parent-child, cover

I took a look at several inherent questions, without finding a solution to the problem I ran into;

The question that comes closest is this one but it doesn't work for me since it uses table and not a grid responsive layout.

What I am trying to achieve would be a grid where the first cell has a child that should fully cover the height and width of the parent cell as in the picture

[image: do not pay attention to the black shape above the text it is an aesthetic element floating around the page]

```css
.InAgent{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2fr, 1fr) ;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    place-content: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1500;
    height: 134vh;
    font-size: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: fit-content;
    justify-items: stretch;
}  
    
.pic { 
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    place-items: center;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.roles { 
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; 
    background-color: #913131;
}


.bio { 
    background-color: grey;
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3; 
}

   
.PrJojo{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 30vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/xf8c0rS/lios-labs-151.jpg');
    background-attachment: local;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section class="InAgent" id="InJojo">
 
  <div class="pic">
    <div class="PrJojo"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="roles">
    <ul>Roles: Board member...
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bio"> 
    <ul>Jo is an artist-curator, cultural ecologist and community weaver born in Poland. Dancing through life
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</section>
```

Comment: You can use `background-size: cover`, although that might cut off some parts of the image. So then you can decide what part of the image to show with positioning. More info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem cause the img is covering the div is the div class"PrJojo" that doean't cover the parent cell div class "pic"

Comment: @ralph.m positioning the child absolutly top '0' or bottom '0' bring the child out of the grid layout, and what do u mean with 'it seems like a problem you don't need' ? I need to use the img in the child and not in the parent for further Js interactions

Comment: I'v snippet the code

Answer (score 0):

If you use fixed sizes, like `width: 50vw` and `height: 3vh`, also `height: 134vh;` you are generating a fixed layout in some way. You must have to generate a really responsive layout to get accurate display in every screen, don't use fixed sizes (only in certain cases).

Try this approach, less code, less rigid, more responsive, more accurate.

Happy coding!

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}

.bio {
    background-color: grey;
}

.roles {
   background-color: #913131;
}

.picture {
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/xf8c0rS/lios-labs-151.jpg');
  background-attachment: local;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1 picture"></div>
  <div class="div2 bio">
    <ul>
      <li>Jo is an artist-curator, cultural ecologist and community weaver born in Poland. Dancing through life</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="div3 roles">
    <ul>
      <li>Roles: Board member...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```